# How do I refresh Listview upon exiting from Contextual Action Mode

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have SherlockListFragment which implements contextual action mode. The onActionItemClicked method update entries in database. How do I refresh SherlockListFragment to update the Listview?

Here is my SherlockListFragment class with ActionMode.Callback

```
    public class FavListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

       ...        
       @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            ...
            getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    if(mActionMode != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    mActionMode = getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(actionModeCallback);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

            ...

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                mActionMode = null;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.deleteMenu:
                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    Uri singleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ZikrContentProvider.CONTENT_FAV_ID_URI, id);
                    values.put(FAV, 0);
                    getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().update(singleUri, values, null, null);
                    mode.finish();


                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }; 
    }
```

I have tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, but the ListView doesn't get updated. I've also tried getLoaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, arg), but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to specify argument3. My adapter is SimpleCursorAdapter. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call invalidateViews() to refresh ListFragment...

listFragment.getListView().invalidateViews();

Answer (score -1):

Get your Fragment to implement both ActionMode.Callback and

```
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

then you can call

```
getLoaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, **this**)
```

from onActionItemClicked